# how to write specific ajax post in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery ajax post and when a user wirte and press enter in a messagebox this ajax triggers. but I want to make a specific post, so when a user write specific message then the ajax triggers. I used something like:

```
if(input == "Hello")
         AjaxPost(input);
```

but it works for the first time and when I write something else than "hello" and then I write "hello" it does not trigger my ajax. but I do not think this way works, how can I write a specific ajax message?

```
AjaxPost : function(data) {

      $.ajax({
       type : "POST",
       url : "/api/user",
       datatype : "application/json",
       contentType: " text/plain",
       data : dataAttribute,
       success : function(data) {

       },
       error : function(error) {

       },
```

Comment: you need to give more info about where the message is written and how the change event is handled

Answer (score 0):

If it's a input or a textarea, then bind the `change` or the `blur` event to the element.

```
$('messagboxIdentifier').change(function() {
     if(this.value === 'Hello') {
          // call the method here
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but still the same problem

Comment: but what if I want to write something like this: if messagboxIdentifier changed AND this.value == 'Hello'? How can I write this?

Comment: You need to replace `messagboxIdentifier` with either the id, elemment or the class of the element. The `change` handler takes care of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#messagboxIdentifier').change(function() {
     if(this.value === 'Hello') {
          // call the method here
     }    
});
```

A # symbol is to be used with the id to bind it properly, was it done ?